# Multiple Database connection JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to connect two database using spring boot JPA

Application.properties :

## Application configuration.

```
server.port=8102

# Hibernate configuration.
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
app.datasource.cardHolder.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server:22;databaseName=DB1
app.datasource.cardHolder.username=name
app.datasource.cardHolder.password=psw
app.datasource.cardHolder.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

server.path=F:\\

app.datasource.card.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server:22;databaseName=DB2
app.datasource.card.username=uname
app.datasource.card.password=psw
app.datasource.card.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

# Logging configuration.
logging.level.com.springboot.storedprocedure=DEBUG
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
```

com.app.configuration

CardConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "cardEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "cardTransactionManager")
public class CardDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.card")
    public DataSourceProperties cardDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.card.configuration")
    public DataSource cardDataSource() {
        return cardDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

//    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "first")
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "cardEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(cardDataSource())
                .packages(Card.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager cardTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("cardEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(cardEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

}
```

CardHolder :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.repository2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "cardHolderEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "cardHolderTransactionManager")
public class CardHolderDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.cardholder")
    public DataSourceProperties cardHolderDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.cardholder.configuration")
    public DataSource cardholderDataSource() {
        return cardHolderDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }
    
//    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "second")
    @Bean(name = "cardHolderEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardHolderEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(cardholderDataSource())
                .packages(CardHolder.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager cardHolderTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("cardHolderEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardHolderEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(cardHolderEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

CardConfi is set the JPARepository properly and return data based on DB2 but same way i have added EntityManger in CardHolderRepository like below,

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(value= {
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name= "callSP", procedureName= "cardmsSP", parameters= {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode= ParameterMode.IN, name= "Name", type= String.class)
        })
})

public class CardHolder implements Serializable {

 //getter setter
}
```

com.app.repository2

```
@Repository
public class CardHolderDao {
    
    @Autowired
    SPRepository spRep;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<CardHolder> gecardtHolderList (String input) {
     
     return em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("cardmsSP").setParameter("Name", input).getResultList();
}

}
```

com.app.repository2

```
public interface SPRepository extends JpaRepository<CardHolder, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CardHolder>{

    
}
```

Problem is that EntityManager em is always pointing to DB2 instead of DB1. where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder#persistenceUnit`

```
@Bean(name = "cardHolderEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardHolderEntityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
           .dataSource(cardholderDataSource())
           .packages(CardHolder.class)
           .persistenceUnit("cardHolderEntityManager") // !!!
           .build();
}
```

And then

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "cardHolderEntityManager")
EntityManager em;
```